# bcrypt.compareSync doesn't work on sequelize

Tags: javascript, post, ecmascript-6, sequelize.js, bcrypt

Can someone help me figure out why `bcrypt.compareSync` function doesn't work on my case :

**models/patient.js**

```
const bcrypt = require('bcryptjs');

module.exports = (sequelize, Sequelize) => {
    const Patient = sequelize.define('Patient', {
        email: {
            type: Sequelize.STRING,
            allowNull: false,
        },
        password: {
            type: Sequelize.STRING,
            allowNull: false,
        },
    }, {
        classMethods: {
            associate: (models) => {
                // associations can be defined here
            }
        },
        instanceMethods: {
            //
            verifyPassword: function(password,hash) {
                bcrypt.compareSync(password,hash);
            }
        }
    });
    return Patient;
};
```

**controllers/patients.js EDITED**

```
retrieve(req, res) {
    return Patient
        .find({
            where: {
                email: req.body.email,
            }
        })
        .then(patient => {
            const result = Patient.build().verifyPassword(req.body.password, patient.password);
            if (!result) {
                console.log('wrong password')
            } else return res.status(201).send(patient);
        })
}
```

My request supposed to return the patient that correspond to the email and password that is typed on the request but it return this :

**EDIT** : Error issue resolved but still getting false result (it returns the 'wrong password' string) even when I make a request with the right password.

Comment: So what is the error?

Comment: My request return nothing but it's supposed to return the patient that correspond to the email and password that is typed on the request.

Comment: You have `error`, why don't you output it? Never ignore errors, they are there for a reason.

Comment: I got this now 
`Unhandled rejection Error: Illegal arguments: undefined, string`

Comment: What line did throw that error?

Comment: So... ? You know the line, you know the error message. Any thoughts?

Comment: this line : 
`bcrypt.compareSync(password,hash)`
an this one :
`const result = Patient.build().verifyPassword(req.params.password,patient.password);`

Comment: Check the error message (again), it says the first argument is `undefined`.

Comment: I resolved the error issue,but it returns now false even if my password is right please check the edit

Comment: Well, you now know how to debug: check every variable. Make sure everything has the value you expect to have. Now you can follow the same idea repetitively until your code works as expected.

Comment: Alright I'll try that thank's for the help :)

Comment: Have fun ;-) .....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You forgot to return anything from `verifyPassword`.

```
verifyPassword: function(password,hash) {
    return bcrypt.compareSync(password,hash);
}
```

Now it will return `true` if password is correct, otherwise `false`.